# Select * with specific alias [syntax]

Tags: sql

I want to use select * to select all the fields from a table but I also want to use an alias on just one field.  Is it possible? If so what would the syntax be.

Example

```
select *,
item1 as hats
from factory
```

I have not been able to make anything like this work, Thanks!

Comment: You do not need to name all fields. OP's statement is valid as is also `select col1, col2 as mycol from mytable` At least on all SQL implementations I know.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I just tried

```
select *, item1 as hats from factory
```

on mysql and postgres and on both DBMS it runs fine. Only take into consideration that you get two columns with item1. One column named item1 and one named hats.

Comment: Would it be possible to remove the duplicate?

Comment: Well I dont know why it didnt work I am using sql server 2007 I think either way its all good now Thanks! Duplicate doesnt actually matter and probably should actually be there in hindsight of my issue

Comment: you saved my life!

Answer (score 4):

That should work, but keep in mind that your item1 column will be *duplicated*!

Suppose your table has the columns (id, item1, item2) then your proposed select will return (id,item1,item2,hats).

Answer (score 3):

It's valid in `MS Sql Server` as well but the column you are alias'ng will be duplicated.
Tried the query in Sql server 2005 and it did worked.

```
select *,col2 as 'customcol' from table1
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible to use that format however, use of `Select *` is not recommend. It is better to enumerate the columns you want. Some database products may balk if the list of columns in combination with your aliased column produces a duplicate column name. However, again, you can solve this by enumerating the columns.

Comment: I dont trust enumeration... because I dont understand it in this context. Do you have an example?

Comment: @tylercomp "enumerate" = "list out the columns instead of using *". I.e., be explicit about the columns you want and do not rely on *.

Comment: Oh I always imagined it as like listing select 1,2,3,4,5 and getting the first five columns... but I dont think I can take the route of listing them out... too many to be immediately feasible; hurts readability

Comment: @tylercomp - There are short cuts in Management studio for getting the list of columns however perhaps the question you should be asking is why you need to return so many columns of data in a single call.